# Highlight duplicates and copy to new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I have a large sheet of server names, ~12,000 rows.  I need to highlight any duplicate server names and then copy them to a new sheet.  I have a script to highlight the cells, that works great (thank you Kurt Kaiser). But, I can't figure out how to write the duplicates (all instances) to a new sheet.  Here's the snippet of the code that highlights the duplicates.

```
// Highlight all instances of duplicate values in a column
function highlightColumnDuplicates(indexes) {
  var column = 1;
  for (n = 0; n < indexes.length; n++) {
    sheet.getRange(indexes[n] + 1, column).setBackground("yellow");
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: not sure why the codes didn't format properly, sorry.

Comment: (For formatting: you just needed an extra blank line before the code section.)

Comment: Nevertheless I suspect that the script can work quite slow if there are hundreds duplicates. It sets background for every duplicate. But it would be way faster to set all backgrounds for the range (column) with one step with `setBackgrounds()` method.

Comment: While it might slow down performance, you can use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates. Use this rule if cell is A1 and then apply to the entire column. `=countif(A:A,A1)>1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case here is another solution:

```
function main() {
  const duplicates = highlightColumnDuplicates();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Duplicates') || ss.insertSheet('Duplicates');
  const dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange(1,1,duplicates.length,1);
  dest_range.setValues(duplicates.map(x=>[x]));
}

function highlightColumnDuplicates() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const data  = range.getValues().flat();  

  // returns true if 'x' is repeated in 'arr'
  const is_duplicate = (x,arr) => arr.indexOf(x) != arr.lastIndexOf(x);

  // get indexes (row numbers) of duplicates in data (in the column)
  const indexes = data.map((x,i) => is_duplicate(x,data) ? i : '').filter(String);

  // change backgrounds like a sir
  const colors = range.getBackgrounds();
  indexes.forEach(x => colors[x][0] = "yellow");
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);

  // get duplicates from the data via indexes
  const duplicates = Array.from(new Set(indexes.map(x => data[x])));  

  return duplicates;
  
}
```

It will make yellow background for all cells with duplicates on current sheet in column `A` and copy the duplicates on a sheet with name `Duplicates`.

---

### Update

If you need to get full rows and all instances of the duplicates here is the modified code:

```
function main() {
  const duplicates = highlightColumnDuplicates();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Duplicates') || ss.insertSheet('Duplicates');
  const dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange(1,1,duplicates.length,duplicates[0].length);
  dest_range.setValues(duplicates);
}

function highlightColumnDuplicates() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow());
  const data  = range.getValues().flat();  

  // returns true if 'x' is repeated in 'arr'
  const is_duplicate = (x,arr) => arr.indexOf(x) != arr.lastIndexOf(x);

  // get indexes (row numbers) of duplicates in data (in the column)
  const indexes = data.map((x,i) => is_duplicate(x,data) ? i : '').filter(String);

  // change backgrounds like a sir
  const colors = range.getBackgrounds();
  indexes.forEach(x => colors[x][0] = "yellow");
  // range.setBackgrounds(colors);

  // get duplicates from the data via indexes
  const data_all  = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const duplicates = indexes.map(x => data_all[x]);

  return duplicates;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Google App Scripts to create a duplicates list to a new sheet. This function would do it for all values in a column a. `=Unique(filter(List!A:A,not(isblank(List!A:A)),Countif(List!A:A,List!A1:A)>1))`

[You can see an example here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oYKuEaU0jWK0Z2fHdCUEbFmYYYTbr4WKgkUtnfK1tMg/edit#gid=1999459037)

However if you do want an app scripts solution, the below code should also work. The same sample google sheet also shows this on a different tab.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function listDuplicates(someRange) {
  var firstList = someRange;
  var singleList = [];
  var dupList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < firstList.length; i++) {
    var aRow = firstList[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < aRow.length; j++) {
      var theOutput = aRow[j];
      if (theOutput != '') {
        if (singleList.includes(theOutput)) {
            dupList.push(theOutput);
        } else {
            singleList.push(theOutput);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return Array.from(new Set(dupList));
}
```